# select2 Tagging with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I just started using [select2][1] and I'm working on a project that needs a list of tags (like on StackOverflow) that is populated from a JSON data source. I'm using an example found on this question: [Tagging With Ajax In Select2][2] but I'm having some trouble getting it to work.

```
        // Testing JSON load
        $("#testJsonLoad").select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
            createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {

                if ($(data).filter(function () {
                    return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
                }).length === 0) {
                    return {
                        id: term,
                        text: term
                    };
                }
            },
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'data.json',
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        q: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

Just for testing purposes the data.json page has this data in it:

```
{
"data": [
    { "id" : 1, "text" : "Alabama" },
    { "id" : 2, "text" : "Alaska" },
    { "id" : 3, "text" : "Arizona" },
    { "id" : 4, "text" : "Arkansas" },
    { "id" : 5, "text" : "California" },
    { "id" : 6, "text" : "Colorado" },
    { "id" : 7, "text" : "Connecticut" },
    { "id" : 8, "text" : "Delaware" },
    { "id" : 9, "text" : "District of Columbia" },
    { "id" : 10, "text" : "Florida" },
    { "id" : 11, "text" : "Georgia" },
    { "id" : 12, "text" : "Hawaii" },
    { "id" : 13, "text" : "Idaho" } ]
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting this error:
this.text is undefined - Line 78

```
return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
```

I am thinking it may have something to do with the way my JSON is formatted. I've tried a few different formats out and most of my research online hasn't yielded positive results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I needed to call the data.data (in my example) in the results ajax function.

Example:

```
 results: function (data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data.data
                };
            }
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Answer (score 2):

Results is expecting **id** and **text** nodes in the json, you can either tell your JSON to ouput the results using these node names or specify which to use in the JS:

Example from site:

```
query: function (query) {
  var data = {results: []}, i, j, s;
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    s = "";
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {s = s + query.term;}
    data.results.push({id: query.term + i, text: s});
  }
  query.callback(data);
}
```

Comment: id and text fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put debugger before if ($(data).filter(function () and check what you have got in $(data)

Comment: Mine returns: ```[Object { tag={name="Name of tag"}}]```

Comment: This is invalid JSON. it should be: { tag:{name:"Name of tag"}}

Comment: Sorry that is just the format Firebug was reporting / formatting the output. The JSON is actually correct, see my answer...